# Getting gas price on (any) chain

Tags: solidity, gas-price, oracles

In a multichain app, in which txs results depend on the gas price in that precise moment, how can I reliably get the gas price **on chain**?

AFAIK I only see a GasPrice Chainlink oracle for Ethereum. What about the rest? How does one deal with it?

Comment: Where do you want the gas price, within a smart contract or on a dApp?

Comment: @JoãoPauloMorais on chain (so on a dApp)